# OnLoad event not firing for dynamically appended <style> on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, onload

Does anybody know why the onload event does not fire on iPad on the following case? I've tried using jQuery $.load() and pure javascript but still no avail. My google-fu was insufficient to find an answer :(

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var linkEl = document.createElement('link');
linkEl.type = 'text/css';
linkEl.rel = 'stylesheet';
linkEl.href = "my_stylesheet.css"; 

// This doesn't work on ipad
linkEl.onload = function() {
    alert('css is loaded');
}

head.appendChild(linkEl);
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/cYFYE/

Answer (score 4):

I know that FireFox and Safari do not have `load` events for linked stylesheets, so iOS Safari probably doesn't either. I, personally, get around this by making an ajax request for the stylesheet, then putting the response in a `<style>` tag.

I've updated your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/cYFYE/2/

```
function loadCss(src, callback){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: src,
        success: function(response){
          // Create Stylesheet
          var style = document.createElement('style');
          style.type = 'text/css';
          style.media = 'screen';
          if(style.styleSheet){
            style.styleSheet.cssText = response;
          }else{
            style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response));
          }
          document.head.appendChild(style);
          callback && callback();
        }
    });
}
loadCss('/css/normalize.css', function(){ alert('loaded!'); });
```

Comment: And, if interested, here's the vanilla js for those who don't rely on jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/xGjsk/

Comment: Thanks Regis! :) I think that could do for now because we're loading the stylesheets from the same domain, but we're also thinking of moving some of them to a different domain and then we'll have the same problem again :(